# how to collapse navigation on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

Not sure if this question been answered already.

I'm looking to create a navigation that collapses when the user scrolls. I would like something similar to this site http://adcglobal.org/. The navigation becomes smaller as you scroll. I would like to have mine collapse into a menu (similar to a responsive navigation menu except, this is on scroll and not @media to change screen size).

I'm playing around with jQuery and this is what I have so far. The problem with this is that everything disappears as soon as you start scrolling.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
$("ul").hide();
});
```

I haven't used Javascript/jQuery much to have a good understanding on the library and what can or can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use something like:

```
$("ul").removeClass('top');
$("ul").addClass('scroll');
```

where in your css class `top` you will have all the styles set for when it's at the top, and in class `scroll` you will have all the styles for after you scroll.

You will also likely want check each time the user scrolls the 
value of `$("ul").offSet().top`, if it is 0, you want to add the class `top` back to the element, and remove `scroll`. You can also check that value to make sure a certain amount has scroll prior to changes the classes, eg:

```
if ($("ul").offSet().top > 20){ ... }
```